# x86 memory addressing with function parameters

Tags: assembly, x86

So if I have a procedure where the first formal parameter is an `int[]` and I'm enumerating through that loop, I'm confused about why one piece of code works where another doesn't.  I should be able to do this:

```
#where ebp+8 is the location of the pointer, and ecx is the counter
mov edx, [ebp+ecx*4+8]
```

This gives me a gibberish value for edx, but this code works fine

```
mov edx, [ebp+8]
mov edx, [edx+ecx*4]
```

I don't understand the difference between those statements.

Comment: I must be getting old. I don't remember any `ecx*4` in x86 assembler.

Comment: @JohnSaunders: You're forgetting the [SIB](http://ref.x86asm.net/coder64.html#sib_byte_32_64) byte (of course the intel manuals also describe it).

Comment: Thanks for the link. I didn't forget it. I stopped dealing with x86 assembler before 64 bit processors came out.

Comment: @JohnSaunders: It works on all i386 compatible processors (though the link might lead you to believe otherwise). Even if you don't do much assembly coding by hand you have probably seen them in disassembly where stuff like `lea eax, [eax+eax*4]` is common for `eax *= 5`.

Comment: Nope. Stopped programming x86 assembler with an 80286 device driver for MS-DOS/PC-DOS. The binary instruction layout must be quite different. Seems almost as sophisticated as the VAX instruction set, which is where I moved to after that. Again, thanks for the link and the nostalgia.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I didn't realize just how old sk00l you were :). If you want to keep you sanity I suggest you never look into how recent opcodes are encoded on x86 (3 byte opcodes? check. mandatory prefixes that determine the instruction? [check](http://ref.x86asm.net/coder64.html#x0F38)).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are different:

In the first code:

```
mov edx, [ebp+ecx*4+8]
```

You are loading from the address: `ebp+ecx*4+8`

In the second code:

```
mov edx, [ebp+8]
mov edx, [edx+ecx*4]
```

You first load the value stored at `ebp+8`. Then you use it as the base address for the second load.

In other words, the base address is stored at the memory location pointed to by `ebp + 8`. It is not actually stored in the `ebp` register itself.

Comment: In "C". The first is `edx = ebp[ecx + 2]` while the second is `edx = (ebp[2])[ecx]`.